# To write a function that calculates the value of the vector dy according to the equations which govern this system in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, controls, system

```
RW_pendulum_dynamics(y, m1, m2, l1, wr, g, u)
  I1=;
  I2=;
  dy(1,1) = ;
  dy(2,1) = ;
  dy(3,1) = ;
  dy(4,1) = ;
endfunction
```

I want to fill the above function that will give Derivative of State Vector as output
Inputs:
y - State Vector. In case of inverted RW pendulum, the state variables
are angular position of RW alpha, angular velocity of RW alpha_dot, angle of pendulum
bar theta wrt vertical and angular velocity theta_dot of pendulum
bar.
m1 - Mass of pendulum bar
m2 - Mass of reaction wheel
l1 - Length of pendulum bar
g  - Acceleration due to gravity
u  - Input to the system. Input is the torque acting on the RW.

Comment: This is for RW pendulum

Answer (score 0):

Do the followings steps respectively:

- First write the governing differential equations on a piece of paper.
- Then convert them to a set of first order differential equations by
  selecting appropriate state variables.
- Then write them in your code.

Comment: thank you!! im amazed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! helped me alotttttttt